# py2app - TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, macos, py2app

im trying to build an app using py2app which I had working perfectly fine for ages. In an attempt to clean up my various Python installs / setup virtualenv I think I've totally broken something. I gave up in the end trying to setup virtualenv properly and uninstalled it.

(PS. I was only doing this so I could easily switch between python2 and python3 interpreters in VS Code but VS Code failed to recognise the venvs)

Here is the error I'm getting. I've checked my modules and they seem to be all there in the right place, though some seem to be in the site location and other in the user location - AFAIK this is OK.

Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

```
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.13-x86_64/python2.7-standalone/app/Frameworks
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 18, in <module>
    setup_requires=['py2app']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 129, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/Users/michael/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 825, in run
    self._run()
  File "/Users/michael/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 1040, in _run
    self.run_normal()
  File "/Users/michael/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 1133, in run_normal
    mf = self.get_modulefinder()
  File "/Users/michael/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 984, in get_modulefinder
    debug=debug,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/modulegraph/find_modules.py", line 338, in find_modules
    find_needed_modules(mf, scripts, includes, packages)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/modulegraph/find_modules.py", line 256, in find_needed_modules
    path = m.packagepath[0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: `m.packagepath` is probably a scalar and cannot be indexed.

Comment: Thanks, not sure what that is or why it would have changed though. Like I said, I had py2app working fine for months, building new versions of an app daily until I tried installing/setting up new interpreters.

Comment: Turns out this was to do with missing modules in my env.

Comment: @Michael, which modules were missing?